# mysql query with OR optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

Can the following query be optimized? What indexes can be created?

```
SELECT column_a 
  FROM Table_b 
  JOIN Table_a
 WHERE Table_B.ID_b = Table_A.ID_a 
    OR Table_B.ID_b = Table_A.ID_b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should actually be:

```
SELECT column_a 
  FROM Table_b 
  JOIN Table_a ON Table_B.ID_b IN (Table_A.ID_a, Table_A.ID_b)
```

If you don't provide ON criteria with the JOIN, MySQL accepts this as being a `CROSS JOIN` -- the result is a cartesian product (that's bad, unless that's really what you want).  If I knew which table that `column_a` came from, I might suggest a different approach to the query...

Index the following:

- Table_B.ID_b
- Table_A.ID_a
- Table_A.ID_b

The two columns in TABLE_A could be a covering index, rather than separate ones.

Comment: Tried the above but the explain did not change

Comment: @Se D: Without seeing actual data, there's not much to work with -- sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID_x` fields are keys (primary or unique), this should already be pretty good. (I.e., if they're not, you should make sure that all fields affected by the `WHERE` part are indexed.)

Consider posting an [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) of the query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT column_a FROM Table_b JOIN Table_a
WHERE Table_B.ID_b = Table_A.ID_a OR Table_B.ID_b = Table_A.ID_b;
```

---

From comments:

```
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys                               | key           | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                            |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | Table_b | index | INDEX_ON_ID_b                               | INDEX_ON_ID_b | 3       | NULL | 1507     | Using index; Using temporary                     |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | Table_a | ALL   |ID_a,ID_b,ID_a_column_a, ID_b_column_a_index | NULL          | NULL    | NULL | 29252089 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x306) |
```

Comment: Explain output - 
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                               | key| key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                            |
----------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_b | index | INDEX_ON_ID_b                                                                     | INDEX_ON_ID_b | 3       | NULL |     1507 | Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_a         | ALL   |ID_a,ID_b,ID_a_column_a, ID_b_column_a_index | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | 29252089 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x306) |

Comment: @jensgram - Explain output - | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key| key_len | ref | rows | Extra | ----------+ | 1 | SIMPLE | Table_b | index | INDEX_ON_ID_b | INDEX_ON_ID_b | 3 | NULL | 1507 | Using index; Using temporary | | 1 | SIMPLE | Table_a | ALL |ID_a,ID_b,ID_a_column_a, ID_b_column_a_index | NULL | NULL | NULL | 29252089 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x306

Comment: @jensgram - Any more suggestions?

Comment: @Se D As I read it, there are no suitable indexes on `Table_a`. Are there any indexes defined for that table? (Please post these, if any, on your question.)

Comment: @jensgram | id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys                               | key           | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                            |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | Table_b | index | INDEX_ON_ID_b                               | INDEX_ON_ID_b | 3       | NULL | 1507     | Using index; Using temporary                     |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | Table_a | ALL   |ID_a,ID_b,ID_a_column_a, ID_b_column_a_index | NULL          | NULL    | NULL | 29252089 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x306) |

Comment: The indices on Table_A are - ID_a,ID_b,ID_a_column_a, ID_b_column_a_index, ID_b_ID_a. However the explain does not pick up any of the indices. The index name are self explanatory

Comment: @Se D Hmm, I guess this is where my knowledge ends, then. My last resort would be an `EXPLAIN` when using an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).